# Why is the upload button grayed out in chat?

Tags: support, chat, uploader

I am trying to upload a picture in chat, but the upload button is grayed out. After chatting once, it works correctly. I suppose this is an anti-spam measure, am I correct in that assumption?

Comment: Can we see a picture?

Comment: And make sure the pic has red freehand circles.

Comment: @Servy How about an animated gif (the rage, these days) with red, freehand circles, that oscillate?

Comment: @J.Steen That sounds a lot like work.

Comment: @Servy Someone should write a userscript.

Comment: @J.Steen Using jQuery...

Comment: @Bart jQuery **does** do all things.

Comment: I don't think this is anti-spam at all, I just don't think the upload control can also send text at the same time. Like in iOS, when you send a text message with a picture attached, it actually gets sent as two independent messages.

Answer (score 4):

According to my experience, the Upload button grays out when you write at least one character in the text field. You cannot upload while writing. Compare these two pics (MSO chat):

[image]

and

[image]

I've also found out that in the Beta sites the button does not gray out (visually), but it won't work anyways.